# How do I get the span text within the list item using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have t he following list item:

```
<li class="item" id="44">
  <div class="name">Bogstadveien</div>
  <div>
    <span class="city">Oslo</span>, 
    <span class="country">Norway</span>
  </div>
</li>
```

Upon clicking the list item, I run the script:

```
var list_item = jQuery(this);
var guide_id = list_item.attr('id');
```

How do I get the city and country values?
I've tried using `find`, `closest` and `next`, but I'm not using them correctly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var city = list_item.find('span.city').text();
```

here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/JdcYM/

Answer (score 1):

```
var list_item = jQuery(this);
var guide_id = list_item.attr('id');
var city = jQuery('span.city', list_item).text();
var country = jQuery('span.country', list_item).text();
```

Answer (score 1):

Can find the county and the city by selecting the text from the span after finding it using the find method

```
list_item.find('.city').text()
list_item.find('.country').text()
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter on your clicked on object: http://jsfiddle.net/755x3/